# Создать программно подменю

Tags: java, android

Создаю так:

```
PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    menu1.getMenu().add(0,0,0,"Создать");
    menu1.getMenu().add(2,1,0,"Изменить");
    menu1.getMenu().addSubMenu(2,2,0,"Изменить данные");
    menu1.getMenu().addSubMenu(2,3,0,"Изменить функцию");
```

Результат: все вываливается одним списком, а мне надо, чтобы вначале было два пункта "Создать" и "Изменить", и если на "Изменить" нажимаю, появлялись пункты подменю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы добавляете подменю в корневой элемент меню. Вот оно у вам и на одном уровне с обычными пунктами. Вам надо побавлять подменю к уже существующим пунктам меню. Попробуйте как-то так - найти пункт уже добавленный и в него добавить подменю:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
//так добавится пункт, к корому нельзя добавить под меню
popup.getMenu().add(1, 1, 1, R.string.delete);
//а так добавится в первый уровень меню пункт с именем "submenu"
SubMenu subMenu = popup.getMenu().addSubMenu(0, 0, 0, "submenu");
//а вот так в него можно добавить подменю с именами "subItem0" и "subItem1"
//они появятся с заголовком "submenu"
subMenu.add(0, 0, 0, "subItem0");
subMenu.add(0, 1, 1, "subItem1");
```

Comment: Уже пробовал. После findItem(1) нет возможности добавить.

Comment: @kaaa, обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает.